# how to escape an input() in python after pressing escape

Tags: python

This may seem trivial, but I have trouble stopping an input() in Python when the user wants to cancel data entry and return to the previous part by pressing the escape key. I simply want the code to distinguish the escape key and execute a "break", so the code leaves the while loop and return to the previous menu. Please help.

I tried:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
   break
```

but to no avail!

Comment: When using `input`, Python is simply reading from a file. It's up to whatever *provides* the contents of the file to expose the press of the Escape key in a detectable fashion.

Comment: `input` is a blocking call, you might want another library that would wrap some nasty details of asynchronous console management. Maybe this one https://pypi.org/project/aconsole/

Answer (score 0):

This will not work with the `input()` function, as it is blocking program flow.
There is a bunch of modules that will deal with this.
Here an example using pynput, which you may need to install first with `pip install pynput`:

```py
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc: # escape key
        print("You pressed escape!")
        return False # stop the listener

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using the Escape key, which doesn't have built in support, you can ask the user to enter the EOF/EOT character and catch the EOFError exception, but the method of entry differs by platform.

On Windows, users enter Ctrl+Z followed by Enter.
On MacOSX or Linux, users enter Ctrl+D and it will respond immediately.

It's also possible to catch the Ctrl+C KeyboardInterrupt during an input, but if a user accidentally double taps that they might exit your program entirely

If you're using some other platform besides those, some investigation would be needed, but Ctrl+D should be standard for most terminal entry programs.

```
import platform

if platform.system() == "Windows":
    eof_key = "<Ctrl+Z>"
else:
    eof_key = "<Ctrl+D>"

while True:
    try:
        user_input = input(f"Enter next value or {eof_key} to stop: ")
    except EOFError:   # Ctrl+Z + Enter on Windows, Ctrl+D on Linux/MacOSX
        break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # Ctrl + C - will exit program immediately if not caught
        break
    else:
        print(f"You entered {user_input}")

# Adding a blank line because EOF and KeyboardInterrupt leave cursor on the input line.
print()

print("Program Exit")
```